# How can I build a Android app with local MySQL database?

Tags: android, mysql, local

I would like to build a local database android app with MySQL. Can I do that? Does the user need MySQL server installed in their phone to run the app? Is there any special stuff to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can install MYSQL in phone. You have to connect to the remote server/database as told by @Fahad Alkami above.

You have to use sqlite which is pre-installed in android phone and you can use ORMs for easy like [greenDAO](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/), [sugar](https://github.com/satyan/sugar), etc. Also you can use [realm](https://github.com/realm/realm-java), if you would like to use other than sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the database installed on a server and the user access the database using some API.

You do this only if you need the database to be on your server if the data stored concerns the user only then just have Sqlite database on the user's device. 
Again,You should not connect to the Server-database directly from your application.

Comment: I would like all the data stored in the user's own phone, instead of on a remote server.

Comment: you can use sqlite or realm as database

Comment: @user43506 then don't use a server just have Sqlite database , you create it in the user's device and save all his/her data inside . Here is a tutorial on how to get started with sqlite in android : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm